How to pass a variable from a layout deeper into nested components in Next 15 and TS?
layout.tsx
// src/app/[lang]/layout.tsx
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ lang: 'pl' }, { lang: 'en' }]
}

type Params = Promise<{lang: "en" | "pl" }>;

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: Params;
}) {
  const { lang } = await params; 

  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <body>
          <main>
            {children}
          </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

How can I pass 'lang' variable deeper into nested components and use it? I am using next.js v15.0.3 and TypeScript.

This is not exactly your perfect answer to this question, because you asked about passing props to the children. But just await again for params in your components again if you want to get the "lang" variable of your route in other components.


// src/app/[lang]/page.tsx

type Params = Promise<{ lang: "en" | "pl" }>;

export default async function Home({ params }: { params: Params }) {
  const { lang } = await params;
  return <div>your lang is: {lang}</div>;
}




Will it work for any nested component or only for Layout and Page?

An easy way to do that is using useContext

Basically you define a provider and use it in your main layout file
then access its properties in nested components.

Here's how:
LangProvider.tsx
"use client"

import { createContext, ReactNode, useContext } from "react"

export const useLangContext = () => useContext(LangContext)

export const LangProvider = ({ lang, children }: { lang: string, children: ReactNode }) => {
    const language = useLanguage(lang)

    return <LangContext.Provider value={language}>{children}</LangContext.Provider>
}

const useLanguage = (lang: string) => {
    return { language: lang }
}

const LangContext = createContext<ReturnType<typeof useLanguage>>({
    language: "" as keyof typeof useLanguage,
})

layout.tsx (with LangProvider)
import { LangProvider } from "@/app/LangProvider"

// src/app/[lang]/layout.tsx
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ lang: 'pl' }, { lang: 'en' }]
}

type Params = Promise<{lang: "en" | "pl" }>;

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: Params;
}) {
  const { lang } = await params; 

  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <body>
          <main>
              <LangProvider lang={lang}>
                  {children}
              </LangProvider>
          </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

[nested_component_in_a_page].tsx (should be a client component)
import { useLangContext } from "@/app/LangProvider"

export default function NestedComponentInAPage() {
    const { language } = useLangContext()
    console.log("language => ", language)
}

That's it!
